# Visual Studio 2012 ASP.NET Web Helpers library intellisense is not working

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, razor

I am trying to become more familiar with ASP.NET and was going through ASP.NET Web Page tutorials on asp.net website. Followed instructions on how to install the ASP.NET Web Helpers library (v3.2.3), however it is not being picked up by VS intellisense using razor syntax. Also, after I installed the library, razor templates are no longer available via "Add New Item". What am I missing?

Here is the Web.config content:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Screenshot 1:

[image]

Screenshot 2:

[image]
Please let me know if you need more information on this.

Comment: Are you creating a razor file (there should be an option in screenshot 1 window)? The filename needs to end with `.cshtml`.

Comment: Razor file options become no longer available once helpers library and dependencies are installed.